# Python - Remove a character the second time it is duplicated

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm looking to remove a ',' (comma) from a string, but only the second time the comma occurs as it needs to be in the correct format for reverse geocoding...

As an example I have the following string in python:

```
43,14,3085
```

How would I convert it to the following format:

```
43,143085
```

I have tried using regex and str.split() but have not achieved result yet..

Comment: single line answer , u can replace the first occurence of "," with empty character       s="43,14,3085"               s.replace (",","",1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure that string only contains two commas and you want to remove the last one you can use [`rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) with [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> s = '43,14,3085'
>>> ''.join(s.rsplit(',', 1))
'43,143085'
```

In above `rsplit` splits starting from the end number of times given as a second parameter:

```
>>> parts = s.rsplit(',', 1)
>>> parts
['43,14', '3085']
```

Then `join` is used to combine the parts together:

```
>>> ''.join(parts)
'43,143085'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get rid of all your commas excepts the first one:

```
string = '43,14,3085'
splited = string.split(',')
string=",".join(splited[0:2])
string+="".join(splited[2:])
print(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
i = s.find(',')
s[:i] + ',' + s[i+1:].replace(",", "")
```